# Tab and arrow keys cause issue with onkeypress in a form field

Tags: javascript

I was given a form and told to make it work as is.  The designer had form fields that are using an onkeypress function to allow only numbers.  The problem was if I tried to use the arrow keys or the tab key, I was getting an error.  I looked here on Stackflow and on google and the only solution I found was to add an eventlistner/attachevent(older versions of IE) to disable the arrow keys and tab key on the fields that use the onkeypress function.

Is there a way around this?

As a side note, I wouldn't have made the form this way.  I would have either made them dropdown lists with numeric values or used the html number field.  I could have also used a text box and then on submit check to verify it was a number entered.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use **`onblur` event** on the field.

Rather than validating the key pressed by the user, you should validate once the control is moved out from the field